# Customize the request url in php

Tags: php

I would like to highlight the current tab using the url

```
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$gallerypageurl="http://www.domain.com/gallery/"; 
if ($gallerypageurl==$url){ echo "selected"; }else { echo "";}
```

This highlights the gallery tab when the url is *http://www.domain.com/gallery/*
but my gallery has a pagination in that, so when I go to second page the url is *http://www.domain.com/gallery/2/*.

This won't highlight the current gallery tab because the $url (*http://www.domain.com/gallery/2/*) is not equal to $gallerypageurl (*http://www.domain.com/gallery/*).

How do you extract only the page url without the page number /2/ or /3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use (for example...) [`stristr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php):

```
if (stristr($url, $gallerypageurl) !== false)
{
  // $gallerypageurl was found in $url
  echo "selected";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with

```
if (strpos($url, $gallerypageurl) !== false) {
    echo 'selected';
}
```

Comment: That does not check where $gallerypageurl is found. It could be part of the domain/subdomains, path, file...

Answer (score 0):

This function works **only** if section's name is in the first segment of the URL path.

```
function inSection($section, $url)
{
    $path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    if(preg_match('@^/([^/]+)/?@', $path, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1] === $section;
    }
    return false;
}

echo inSection('gallery', 'http://www.domain.com/gallery/2/')
     ? 'selected' : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You may split the request uri into array using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function, then check the array keys are the ones you need to:

```
    $uri = 'http://www.domain.com/gallery/2';
    $parts = explode('/', $uri);
    echo 'gallery' === $parts[3] ? 'selected' : '';
```

Call `array_shift` twice before, to skip the `http` and domain name and have array indexed from 1.

BTW, you should sanitize the `$_SERVER` keys before further processing.